# How to get the next day in a week

Tags: javascript

I have created a 7 day weather widget. I have the current day which is today but the next day is incorrect. For example today is Friday, so the next day weather info should be for Saturday but it's showing Sunday.

As you can see below, I have the days of the week in an array and accessing the weather data by the dark sky API.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
var days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
                    var weatherData = data.daily.data.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.daily.data.length-1; i++) {
                        var dailyTemp = {
                            day: days[ (i+1) % days.length]
                    };
```

Comment: my guess is that `data.daily.data[0]` is not a sunday

Comment: what's the result for `data.daily.data`?

Comment: @Thomas data.daily.data[0] is a Sunday because when I put data.daily.data[1] then Monday shows instead of Sunday

Comment: @ Yahiya  the result is an array (8) which shows all the weather info for specific days

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using data.daily.data.length-1 ?

Try it without and it shows the correct order:

```
var days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
var weatherData = 7;
for (var i = 0; i < weatherData; i++) {
  var dailyTemp = {
    day: days[(i + 1) % days.length]
  }
  console.log(dailyTemp);
};
```

{
day:"Mon"
}
{
day:"Tues"
}
{
day:"Wed"
}
{
day:"Thurs"
}
{
day:"Fri"
}
{
day:"Sat"
}
{
day:"Sun"
}

Comment: I use data.daily.data.length-1 because thats how I am getting the information from the api.  I need the the weather info so it shows up for the correct day.

Comment: @Saveena how does your api response (JSON) looks like ? can you give us an example ? you're using the Dark Sky API, according to the documentation the data.daily.data.length is 39, correct (https://darksky.net/dev/docs#forecast-request) ?

Comment: daily:
data: (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]